# How to compare in MS Chart with historical data

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mschart

I need to display two series in Microsoft chart at on x axis. I have two different data table for two different date period. I also need to display date as tool-tip for different series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple line chart showing last year sales to bar chart of this year sales.

```
        chart1.Series.Clear();

        string[] months = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr" };
        double[] thisYearSales = { 10000.23, 98000, 95876, 78097 };
        double[] lastYearSales = { 99000, 99000, 90876, 88097 };

        Series thisYear = chart1.Series.Add("this year");
        thisYear.Points.DataBindXY(months, thisYearSales);

        Series lastYear = chart1.Series.Add("last year");
        lastYear.Points.DataBindXY(months, lastYearSales);
        lastYear.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Answer (score 0):

Samples here (and download) [MSChart Samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

Comment: Thanks for you replay. But i have already downloaded the sample. i have't find historical data compare in the sample.

Comment: Let's say you have to compare sales from last year to this year by month.  You would create 2 series.  The first would have Y data points as total sales for this year by month (eg. Jan - Dec).  Then your second series would have total sales for last year by month (also Jan - Dec).  Each series can be a diff type so the first could be a bar graph and the second could be a line chart. (Months is your x axis and must have the same values for both series so that they're  plotted over each other).